# Create Callable jQuery Function for Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find an exact answer for this.

I'm working with a Bootstrap 3 skin I purchased which contains some form UI elements to create nicer selects, radios etc.

But they are all called via selector on dom ready like so:

```
$('select[data-toggle="dropdown-select"]').each(function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```

The problem is I have forms that load via ajax so those forms don't get styled since the .each loop is already executed.

Is there a way I can wrap the selector call into a callable function without stopping it from just firing on dom ready?

Or should I just duplicate the work into a separate function of it's own?

I tried something like this:

```
$.fancySelect = function () {
    $('select[data-toggle="dropdown-select"]').each(function() {
        // do stuff here
    }); 
}
```

but this stopped the selectors from working on their own.

Comment: Create a function that takes in a jQuery element as the parameter and this function applies the css to said parameter. Call the function after each of your AJAX calls is complete

Comment: So just duplicate all these selector calls into individual named functions.  I guess that's fine. Thanks.

Comment: The ones on page load can stick in the each loop, but the individual AJAX ones will need to be called, or you can chain all the AJAX calls together and do it at once

Comment: How do I write the function so I can call it on the element itself? Like this: `$('select[name=\'zone_id\']').html(html).fancySelect();`